# Get input variable from tkinter Python form when there is a class

Tags: python-3.x, forms, class, tkinter

I have this code that works in so far as it creates a very basic form in Python  3 and tkinter. What I want to capture is the text (by pressing the button)  that is entered into the form text box. My problem is my misunderstanding of classes, as I cannot for love nor money get the variable, it always seems to be undefined. So my first question is what is the correct way of getting this, so the button prints the variable, and secondly what am I missing here? What is the idea behind putting variables in a class that cannot be accessed outside of them, or what is the right way to ensure they are?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class App:


    def __init__(self, root):
        #setting title
        root.title("undefined")
        #setting window size
        width=600
        height=500
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        GButton_815=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_815["bg"] = "#efefef"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_815["font"] = ft
        GButton_815["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_815["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_815["text"] = "Run"
        GButton_815.place(x=50,y=100,width=70,height=25)
        GButton_815["command"] = self.GButton_815_command

        GLineEdit_786=tk.Entry(root)
        GLineEdit_786["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLineEdit_786["font"] = ft
        GLineEdit_786["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLineEdit_786["justify"] = "left"
        GLineEdit_786["text"] = "Entry"
        GLineEdit_786.place(x=190,y=100,width=260,height=30)

        GLabel_146=tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLabel_146["font"] = ft
        GLabel_146["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_146["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_146["text"] = "Video ID"
        GLabel_146.place(x=170,y=70,width=70,height=25)

    def GButton_815_command():
        vidIQInput = GLineEdit_786.get()
        print(vidIQInput)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

It is this code that is defeating me

```
def GButton_815_command():
    vidIQInput = GLineEdit_786.get()
    print(vidIQInput)
```

Which always gives this result

```
vidIQInput = GLineEdit_786.get()
NameError: name 'GLineEdit_786' is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `GLineEdit_786` is a local variable inside `__init__()`, so it cannot be accessed outside the function.  Change it to instance variable `self.GLineEdit_786` instead.

Comment: Could you please be exact, I am not following you. What line of code needs changing?

Comment: My comment is very obvious if you know what *local* and *instance* variables are.

Comment: Clearly, I don't. Could you please explain, possibly with an example? I have already declared in my question that I do not completely understand classes. I have tried substituting GLineEdit_786 with self.GLineEdit_786 and that did not work.

Comment: As I said, change all `GLineEdit_786` to `self.GLineEdit_786`.

Comment: I get this error if I do as above
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: GButton_815_command() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: You were nealrly right. The answer is add self and also to add self to the function, you left that out. 
def GButton_815_command(self):
     vidIQInput = self.GLineEdit_786.get()
     print(vidIQInput)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add self to each of the variables I want to access outside the class and then to the function. I won't mark this question as answered yet because the solution provided by acw1668 does not explain why. Would "root" or even "anything" have worked instead of "self". What does "self" and "root" mean in the context of a class?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class App:


    def __init__(self, root):
        #setting title
        root.title("undefined")
        #setting window size
        width=600
        height=500
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.GButton_815=tk.Button(root)
        self.GButton_815["bg"] = "#efefef"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        self.GButton_815["font"] = ft
        self.GButton_815["fg"] = "#333333"
        self.GButton_815["justify"] = "center"
        self.GButton_815["text"] = "Run"
        self.GButton_815.place(x=50,y=100,width=70,height=25)
        self.GButton_815["command"] = self.GButton_815_command

        self.GLineEdit_786=tk.Entry(root)
        self.GLineEdit_786["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        self.GLineEdit_786["font"] = ft
        self.GLineEdit_786["fg"] = "#333333"
        self.GLineEdit_786["justify"] = "left"
        self.GLineEdit_786["text"] = "Entry"
        self.GLineEdit_786.place(x=190,y=100,width=260,height=30)

        GLabel_146=tk.Label(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLabel_146["font"] = ft
        GLabel_146["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_146["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_146["text"] = "Video ID"
        GLabel_146.place(x=170,y=70,width=70,height=25)

    def GButton_815_command(self):

        vidIQInput = self.GLineEdit_786.get()       
        print(vidIQInput)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```